# Want to match the pattern in text file

Tags: java, regex

This is my code

```
import java.io.*;

public class Random
{  
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
FourWords ob1=new FourWords();
FiveWords ob2= new FiveWords();
SixWords ob3= new SixWords();



BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


int no;


do
{
    System.out.println("\n1:- Four words Security");
    System.out.println("2:- Five words Security");
    System.out.println("3:- Six words Security");
    System.out.println("4:- Enter 4 to exit");
    
    
     no =Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    
    if(no>4)
    {
        System.out.println("Please provide an valid input");
    }
    
    
switch(no)
{
    case 1:
    ob1.four();
    break;
    
    case 2:
    ob2.five();
    break;
    
    case 3:
    ob3.six();
    break;
    
    
    
}
}
while(no<=3); 
    
    
}
 
}

class FourWords
{
    public void four() throws IOException
    {
        
        int arr[]= new int[5];
        int randomNum,minimum=1,maximum=4;  
        int i;
        
        System.out.print("\n");
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
arr[i]=minimum +(int)(Math.random()*maximum);

System.out.print(arr[i]);
System.out.print("\t");

    }
    
    }
    
}

class FiveWords
{
    void five()
    {
int randomNum,minimum=1,maximum=5;
System.out.print("\n");
for(int j=1;j<=5;j++)
{   
randomNum=minimum +(int)(Math.random()*maximum);

System.out.print(randomNum);    
System.out.print("\t");
    }
    }   
}

class SixWords
{
    void six()
    {
        int randomNum,minimum=1,maximum=6;  
System.out.print("\n");
for(int k=1;k<=5;k++)
{
        randomNum=minimum +(int)(Math.random()*maximum);

System.out.print(randomNum);
System.out.print("\t");
}       
}
    
}

class DiceWare 
{
    
    public void dice() throws IOException
    {
        
        FileInputStream fin= new FileInputStream("diceware_wordlist.pdf");
        int ch;
        while((ch=fin.read())!=-1)
        System.out.println((char)ch);
        
        fin.close();
    }
    
    
}
```

I want to match the `randomNum` value to the text file.

suppose the `randomNum` value is 11163  and i want to match these strings inside the text file

for example:-

**11163  about**

and want to print those words which is corresponding to the patterns.

like **about** in above example

so how i will do this

please help me

Comment: Please include the sample data, desired output, and what you've tried so far. No one wants to go look at a screenshot of a text file that has no reason to exist, and that we can't even tell how much/what kind of whitespace is present. I'd suggest reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok thanks for giving me suggestion

Answer (score 0):

1. Get input from command line via [args](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) to main().
2. Read the file line by line, and compare the second value to the user input with a regular expression [pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) match.

Comment: how i will do it can you give me a example.

Comment: I think you won't get my question. this is my question. Suppose i have a string 
Ex:- 
**String s="12345";**

And i want to match this string value to the text file which i already connect  to my program .
And the text file contain 
**12345 about**
And i want to print the correspond string to 
**12345**
Which is **about** here.
How i will do it. i hope you or somebody will help me

Answer (score 0):

First convert the array of random into string and then match it in file..

For example..

public class Demo1 {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String arr="12345";
            try{
            FileInputStream fin= new FileInputStream("\\demo\\demo.txt");
            {
                final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fin);
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                   final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
                   if(lineFromFile.contains(arr)) { 
                       // a match!
                       System.out.println("I found " +arr+ " in file ");
                       break;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       System.out.println("No data found");
                   }
                }   
            }
            fin.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
                System.out.print("Error");
            }
        }
```

}